# Find the standard distribution of a Markov chain with a non-diagonalizable transformation matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I'm trying to find the standard distribution $\pi$ of any Markov chain (assuming that it exists). However, the corresponding transformation matrix $P$ may or may not be necessarily diagonalizable, yet diagonalization seems to be the only process I can find to get $\pi$ where $\pi P = \pi$. Is there any other way?

For example, say I have the transformation matrix
\begin{bmatrix}0&2/3&1/3&0&0\\0&0&0&3/7&4/7\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

In this case, I know that the standard distribution $\pi$ is equal to
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1/3&2/7&8/21\\\end{bmatrix}

Is there some formula or algorithm I can apply to get this distribution from any transformation matrix?

Comment: Not sure if there is a problem with translation to English, but it seems you are asking for the stationary distribution $\pi$ that satisfies $\pi P = \pi$, where P is the transition matrix? A standard way to find such $\pi$ is to find a vector in the nullspace of $P^\top - I$.

Comment: what is your definition of "standard distribution" ?  This does not seem to make much sense since your chain is *reducible* into a 2 state transient class and 3 single vertex classes recurrent classes

Comment: @user8675309 I have edited my question to clarify "standard distribution." I am trying to find $\pi$ where $\pi P = \pi$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, that is what I am trying to find. I am not fluent in linear algebra, though, so I'd really appreciate it if you could explain the method you mentioned or link something that does.